# Universal binary doesn't have "open using rosetta"

Tags: xcode, macos, apple-silicon, rosetta-2

In Xcode 12, created a small universal app.
The app "Get Info" shows two checkboxes: "Stationery pad" and "Locked", but not "Open using Rosetta", which I need.

I verified that the binary is universal (has two architectures: x86_64 and arm64).

Is there a hidden option or a info.plist flag I must enable for that?

Comment: "Stationery pad" shouldn't be shown for apps. Is this actually a full application (i.e. a directory with a name ending in ".app", with a "Contents" subdirectory, which contains Info.plist, version.plist, a MacOS subdirectory, etc), or is it just a bare command-line binary?

Comment: It is a command-line binary. Don't those get a chance to open using Rosetta?

Comment: Command-line binaries aren't run via launch services, like apps are, so the mechanisms are different. Try `arch -x86_64 /path/to/binary`

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks, could you pls post this as an answer, (to be accepted)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To work around this for application development:

You will need to build with this Property List Key [LSRequiresNativeExecution](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/lsrequiresnativeexecution) disabled.

An excerpt from the Apple Documentaion:

> ... this key prevents the system from using the Rosetta translation process to execute the Intel portion of a universal app on Apple silicon.

### For command line programs you can simply do this:

```
arch -x86_64 /path/to/program
```